# Parameter value with space in CURL command gives 404 error

Tags: curl, jersey, http-status-code-404, curl-commandline

I am using jersey to create restful webservices. While using curl to consume webservices with parameter values with white space, I get 404 not found issue. What should be done to mitigate this problem.

Request

```
curl -X GET http://api.local.com:8080/v2/parameters**/parameter1/hello world world** /parameter2/world
```

Response
 HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Answer (score 0):

URL encode the string before passing it, (I have not used jersey before so I can not aid it how to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote(`"`) around your URL as you have space in it. Also by default its GET request. So remove the `-X GET`

```
curl "http://api.local.com:8080/v2/parameters**/parameter1/hello world world** /parameter2/world"
```